# Can a Windows Mobile only show UI after the icon in "Programs" is clicked?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have a application which is written in C# (.net CF), I want it to have the following behavior.
1. The application starts at the background to connect to the server when the device starts.
2. When user click the icon from the programs to show the application UI.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this, at least not in the same process instance. The only way you can come close to doing what you want is to create two processes. The 1st would be the process with no UI that connects to the server. The 2nd would be your actual UI process. You would have to devise a means of interprocess communication (sockets maybe?) to exchange data between the two.

Comment: We found a workaround, the application starts the UI and hide it immediately after it shows, it also starts a thread to connect to the server, and we add some code in the Form.OnActived callback to handle UI show.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an application code using the notification API. The notification API enables you to show icons at taskbar or on home screen (like notification area of desktop windows taskbar). The application itself is started minimized (hidden), if the user clicks the notification icon you can show an UI directly or show a bubble with a link to show your app.

See also http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/104 (notification icon)

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446525.aspx (today screen icon)

edit:

Option three and easiest one: Normally a windows mobile app should only be run once (single instance). To do so, MS Win32 C++ SmartDevice code inserts some code to check for a previously started window with the same titel and class of the currently to start instance. If so, the C++ code does a ShowWindow with the window handle of the previos window and the arg SW_SHOWNORMAL) and then exits. The same can be achieved in Compact Framework where you can chack for a previous started instance in Program.cs WinMain() function. If a previous instance exists, then use ShowWindow() with the handle of the found instance and exit further execution. This way, your app starts minimized but will come to foreground, if it is tried to start again by clicking the program icon (or exe file). In C# you will need FindWindow() and ShowWindow() PInvokes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. The customer want to start from the programs list not the notification .

Comment: Then simply start the app. The app minimizes itself and shows, when clicked again in Programs List.